# Java Variable Manipulation

Tags: java, variables

I'm a bit stumped here, but I'm sure a someone could shed some light on this. I'm creating a program that can handle different label designs and send them to a printer. The only constraints is that the admin/software user controls the variables within the label_type part of the database.

Here is the current logic of the user id label/badges:-

A user is selected which brings up all their details and then we can print a badge/label

The details that are returned on the user_id are as follows and are defined within the class.

```
private String user_id;
private String external_user_id;
private String username;
private String uid;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;
private String telephone;
private String user_group_name;
private String user_group_type;
private String company_name;
private String category;
private String region_name;
```

The label that to be used is selected from a drop down which returns:-

```
private String format;
private String label_data;
private String label_filename;
private String label_directory;
private String label_offset;
private String variables;
```

label_data and variables are the only concern as the other variables depend on the printer.

The printer is selected which just returns values so that the label can be printed.

The label_data can be designed by the customer and to make it data base specific they replace the variables with the following strings

***variable1***
***variable2***
***variable3***
etc

The variable control is within the variables value:-

***variable1***-user_id,***variable2***-external_user_id,***variable3***-username,***variable4***-uid,***variable5***-firstname,***variable6***-lastname,
***variable7***-email,***variable8***-telephone,***variable9***-user_group_name,***variable10***-user_group_type,***variable11***-company_name,
***variable12***-category,***variable13***-region_name

Here is a Zebra ZPL language for a simple user id badge with a barcode:-

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~\\\\n^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD18^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ\\\\n^XA\\\\n^MMT\\\\n^PW609\\\\n^LL0406\\\\n^LS0\\\\n^FT29,63^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**variable5**^FS\\\\n^FT29,106^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**variable6**^FS\\\\n^FO20,339^GB559,0,8^FS\\\\n^BY3,3,160^FT96,294^BCN,,Y,N\\\\n^FD>:**variable4**^FS\\\\n^FO18,121^GB560,0,8^FS\\\\n^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

As you can see it has the following variables inserted into the ZPL

**variable5** = firstname

**variable6** = lastname

**variable4** = uid

I already knew I'd have problems with this. I split the variables around "," and then "-" to get out:-

variable_number        variable_name

**variable1**          user_id

**variable2**          external_user_id

**variable3**          username

etc

Within a for loop I do a find and replace:-

label_data = label_data.replace(variable_number, variable_name);

As you are aware what happens is that the variable names are inserted rather that the value of the predetermined variables that were already returned. I've looked, but I cant figure out how to do this....

The label_data I get out is:-

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~\\\\n^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD18^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ\\\\n^XA\\\\n^MMT\\\\n^PW609\\\\n^LL0406\\\\n^LS0\\\\n^FT29,63^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**firtsname**^FS\\\\n^FT29,106^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**lastname**^FS\\\\n^FO20,339^GB559,0,8^FS\\\\n^BY3,3,160^FT96,294^BCN,,Y,N\\\\n^FD>:**uid**^FS\\\\n^FO18,121^GB560,0,8^FS\\\\n^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

where it should be

CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~\\\\n^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD18^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ\\\\n^XA\\\\n^MMT\\\\n^PW609\\\\n^LL0406\\\\n^LS0\\\\n^FT29,63^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**Joe**^FS\\\\n^FT29,106^A0N,28,28^FH\\\\\\\\^FD**Bloggs**^FS\\\\n^FO20,339^GB559,0,8^FS\\\\n^BY3,3,160^FT96,294^BCN,,Y,N\\\\n^FD>:**236548**^FS\\\\n^FO18,121^GB560,0,8^FS\\\\n^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ

Any help appreciated

Comment: You'll need to show more of your code before we'll be able to get the context

Comment: Are you trying to insert the value of a variable in the ZPL code and you only get the name of the variable inserted? Sorry, I don't know anything about ZPL, it would be interesting to see how you create that code.

Comment: You need to use the **Reflection API** to take the string attribute name (say, "user_id") and turn that into a call on the accessor method (`getUser_id") of the corresponding attribute of a Java object.

Comment: Or, a big `switch` statement would also work: `switch (variable_name) { case "user_id": value = ob.user_id;break; case "firstname": value = ob.firstname; ...}`, then `label_data = label_data.replace(variable_number, value);`. Reflection would give shorter and more maintainable code (plus it's just so cool) but in a pinch the old ways work too.

Comment: 1: Code really isn't important as its just how to use "variable_name" variable to get the variable in the variable lol variable_name = firstname ....... now I need to go and find predefined value of the variable defined in the class as first name in the example above firstname = Joe.
so variable_name = firstname and firtsname = "Joe".

Comment: 2: i'm trying to do a find and replace on the ZPL code to replace the variables with actual values. ZPL is generated from a Zebra Designer tool which the printers understand.

Comment: 3: I was going to do it this way, but if I create other label_types which do different functions, Pallet labels, vehicle labels, then I'd have a massive switch statement

Comment: use a Map. For example in a `HashMap<String, String>` you could put the variable name as `key` and the variable value as map `value`. This is way more dynamic than switch statements and once your map is created and filled (`myMap.put("firstname", "Jon")` ) you only need to get it with `myMap.get("firstname")`.

Comment: HashMap Solved the problem for now. I need to make it a bit more generic, but for now its working. So I have a database driven label, variables, label types, printers and the actual label data.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you are parsing the variables out you are grabbing the wrong part.

```
variable5-firstname
```

In this portion here, after you have split the string by "," you can use indexOf and substring to get the variable value if I am interpreting what you are trying to explain correctly.

```
String[] variables = string.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
...
if(i == 5){ //However you are parsing
    firstname = variables[i].substring(0, variables[i].indexOf("-"));
}
```

Now later when you are replacing it into your ZPL string you will have the actual variable value and not the label.

Comment: String variable_number = "";
String variable_name = "";
                        
 variable_func1 = variables.split(",");
                        
for(int i = 0; i < variable_func1.length; i++) \\13
 {
   variable_func2  = variable_func1 [i].split("-");
   variable_number = variable_func2 [0].trim().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", ""); \\formatted
   variable_name = variable_func2 [1].trim().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");\\formatted
   label_data = label_data.replace(variable_number, variable_name);
  }
  printer_output = label_data;

Comment: String variable_number = "";
String variable_name = "";
                        variable_func1 = variables.split(",");
                        
for(int i = 0; i < variable_func1.length; i++) \\13
 {
   variable_func2  = variable_func1 [i].split("-");
   variable_number = variable_func2 [0].trim().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", ""); \\formatted
   variable_name = variable_func2 [1].trim().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n|\\t)", "");\\formatted
   label_data = label_data.replace(variable_number, variable_name);
  }
  printer_output = label_data;

Comment: there is no actual values held within the variables split, its more of a lookup to another variable Tried to show the code, but its not formatting correctly.